# pass selected value to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove `<td>` using jquery. i need to remove the `<td>` if its contact matching the one in user selected from dropdown. problem is i cant figure out how to pass this value to the function.
this is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === "SELECTED GOES HERE") {
                $td.remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and this is the dropdown creation:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

how can i send selected value to the function? thanks...

Comment: Why is the function accessed through a button click if you want it for a select change? If you can change that, do so. If not, put everything into its own named function, then call it from either the button click or select change.

Answer (score 0):

In the function compare against the selected value directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $("#select1").val()) {
                $td.remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the selected option you just have to do this code:

```
$('select[name=select1]').val()
```

greetings timotheus

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the value into function. Just grab the selected value once button is clicked.
The simpliest way is to use [**`:contains`**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td:contains("+$('select[name="select1"]').val()+")").remove();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqyhsw1L/)**

You may want to go further and remove the selected option aswell (as you probably don't need it anymore) :

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var val = $('select[name="select1"]').val();
    $('td:contains("'+val+'"), option[value="'+val+'"]').remove();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqyhsw1L/1/)**

Answer (score -2):

I created you a fiddle.  I have passed what you want to an ID, and also to your function as a **variable**.

http://jsfiddle.net/37ocy2am/

**HTML**

```
<select name="select1" id="usernames">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
        <option value="stephencarr">Stephen Carr</option>
        <option value="bobjones">Bob Jones</option>
        <option value="ashleysims">Ashley Sims</option>
        <option value="rushgreg">Rush Greg</option>
</select>

<div id="place_name_here">when you select you will get name here. <br>Just change jquery to pass the var somewhere else</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#usernames" ).change(function() {
    var selected_value = $("#usernames").val();
    $("#place_name_here").html(selected_value);

    $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === selected_value) {
                $td.remove();
            }
        });
});//close change function

});
```

**CSS**

```
#place_name_here{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#00277A;
}
```